# dividing two complex columns (Oracle)

Tags: oracle, math

I'm pulling statistical data from our Oracle database. This query...

```
select
    substr(cm.course_name,0,INSTR(cm.course_name,'.',1,1) - 1) as "SUBJECT",
      count(*) as "TOTAL SHELLS",    
      count(case when (cs.size_total = 0 or cm.pk1 not in (select crsmain_pk1 from course_size))
          and not exists (select 1 from course_contents where crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1)
      then 1 else null end) as "EMPTY SHELLS",     
    from course_main cm
    left join course_size cs on cm.pk1 = cs.crsmain_pk1
    where cm.row_status = 0
    and cm.data_src_pk1 in (select pk1 from data_source where batch_uid like ('%2014FA'))
    group by substr(cm.course_name,0,INSTR(cm.course_name,'.',1,1) - 1);
```

...generates this result:

```
--SUBJECT, TOTAL SHELLS, EMPTY SHELLS
--DHY, 40, 19
--HSC, 10, 0
--BIO, 79, 7
```

While this result is useable, I'd like to have the percentage calculated between the last two columns, so I have a result like:

```
--SUBJECT, TOTAL SHELLS, EMPTY SHELLS, % EMPTY
--DHY, 40, 19, 48%
--HSC, 10, 0, 0%
--BIO, 79, 7, 9%
```

The only way to do this AFAIK is to duplicate each `count` statement and use them as the numerator and denominator, but that would mean needlessly recalculating two values we already have -- not to mention making the query clunky and hard to read. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use your query as a subquery to avoid recalculating all.

```
SELECT 
subject as "SUBJECT", 
totalshells as "TOTAL SHELLS", 
emptyshells as "EMPTY SHELLS", 
ROUND((emptyshells / totalshells) * 100) as "% EMPTY"
from
(select
    substr(cm.course_name,0,INSTR(cm.course_name,'.',1,1) - 1) as subject,
      count(*) as totalshells,    
      count(case when (cs.size_total = 0 or cm.pk1 not in (select crsmain_pk1 from course_size))
          and not exists (select 1 from course_contents where crsmain_pk1 = cm.pk1)
      then 1 else null end) as emptyshells,     
    from course_main cm
    left join course_size cs on cm.pk1 = cs.crsmain_pk1
    where cm.row_status = 0
    and cm.data_src_pk1 in (select pk1 from data_source where batch_uid like ('%2014FA'))
    group by substr(cm.course_name,0,INSTR(cm.course_name,'.',1,1) - 1)) s
```

Comment: I knew there HAD to be a better solution. Thanks!